# Update UIElement from AsycTask

Tags: android, uielement

I want to Update Text View ,spinner from AsycTask.Actually what i am doing

I Take the data from server and result return in json form then i parse JSON and populate the data in two Spinner and one textview.How can i update data when i am using Asyctask beacuse Textview Does not update..Here is my code sniped

```
TAG_CONFIG = "xyz"
TAG_CONFIG1 = "yyy"
JSONParser jParser = null;
JSONObject json = null;
jParser = new JSONParser();
json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
    contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONFIG);
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray c = contacts.getJSONArray(i);
        CompanyName = new String[c.length()];
        for (int j = 0; j < c.length(); j++) {
            CompanyName[j] = c.getString(j);
        }


    }
```

similar for tab_confg1...

Answer (score 2):

`doInBackground` is not synced with the main UI thread... thus, you cannot directly update your UI from this method (you'd have to use a `Handler` or `mContext.runOnUiThread()` instead). You may, however, update your UI from `onPostExecute`, as this method is performed on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to access UI from a Non-UI Thread from `doInBackground` .

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your code here to access UI elements

                }
            });
  return "string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**1.** Whenever we **start** an app in Android, we **start on the Dedicated UI Thread**.

**2. Creation of any thread** will drop one **out of the UI Thread**.

**3.** Keeping the UI work in UI thread and Non-UI work in Non-UI thread is advisable, but it
   went on to be the **rule with the release of HoneyComb Android version.**

**4.** Though **Non-UI thread can be used to post the work from it to the UI thread using the handler, Android provides AsyncTask, which helps in Synchronization the work done on the 
 Non-UI thread back to the UI thread**

In **AsyncTask<>**

--->  **doInBackground()**  will handle the NON-UI WORK.

--->  **PostExectue()** will help in post the NON-UI work back to the UI thread.